# Elliptic curve sequences needed for universal forgery

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, elliptic-curves, integer-sequences, cryptography

[Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) (ECDSA) admits [universal forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature_forgery#Universal_forgery_(universal_unforgeability,_UUF)) (UF) if the Attacker can solve the equation
$$z=\frac{f_{k-1}(x,y)f_{k+1}(x,y)}{f_{k}(x,y)^2},$$
where $k$ is unknown, $f_{k}(x,y)$ are [Division polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_polynomials)
and $(x,y)$ are the coordinates of some fixed point $P$ on the elliptic curve $E:y^{2}=x^{3}+Ax+B\;$ (everything is over $\mathbb{F}_p$). This UF is based on the formula for the coordinates of the $k$ th multiple of $P(x,y)$:
$$kP=\left(x-\frac{f_{k-1}(x,y)f_{k+1}(x,y)}{f_{k}(x,y)^2},\ldots\right).$$

It is known that  division polynomials satisfy the following (elliptic divisibility sequence-) recurrence (see Ch. 2 in *Lang S. Elliptic curves: Diophantine analysis. 1978*)
$$f_{m+n}f_{m-n}=f_{m+1}f_{m-1}f_{n}^2-f_{n+1}f_{n-1}f_{m}^2.$$
In particular
$$f_{m+2}f_{m-2}=\alpha f_{m+1}f_{m-1}-\beta f_{m}^2.$$ 
It means that   $h_k:=\frac{f_{k-1}f_{k+1}}{f_{k}^2}$ (needed for UF)
satisfy the recurrence 
$$\tag{$*$}h_{m-1}h_{m}^2h_{m+1}=\alpha h_{m}-\beta.$$

> **Q:** Were the properties of sequences defined by $(*)$ studied before (period lengths, randomness, uniform distribution, ...)? Can $\{h_m\}$ be cryptographically better than $\{f_m\}$?

This is only $\!\!\mod p$-question because over $\mathbb{C}$ such sequences are well-known: $h_n=\wp(z)-\wp(z_0+nz).$ They arise in the study of Somos-4 sequences (see *Hone A. [Elliptic curves and quadratic recurrence sequences](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/S0024609304004163). Bull. Lond. Math. Soc. 2005*.)

The question [Universal forgery based on mathematical problem](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/54503/universal-forgery-based-on-mathematical-problem) about another problems needed for UF was asked at [Crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)  separately.

Comment: Cryptographically better, you mean more secure, equation has less solutions,or  hard to find solutions. It could be certain operations allow for more private solutions, one operation(recurrence?) could change the scheme, others offering more secure factoring type, just difficult.

Comment: @user3483902 By "better" I mean "stronger=secure".